# Creating SiteCollections using SharePoint Management Shell 2013

Tags: powershell, design, bug

I am following the below instruction to create a NHSC, but at point D when I am creating a Team Site, I get the message that the new URL is not found! Do I need to create that before? Am I missing something here?

Create Site Collections for Testing SharePoint & SharePoint Apps:

1. Open SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:
2. Get a reference to the HNSC web application you just created by running the following Windows PowerShell script in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:

   `$hnscWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "SharePoint HNSC Host - 80"}`
3. Create a non-templated site at the root of the web application for Workflow to connect to by executing the following Windows PowerShell script in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:

   `New-SPSite -Name "Root HNSC Site Collection" -Url "http://wingtip.com" -HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -OwnerAlias "WINGTIP\Administrator"`
4. Create a team site by executing the following Windows PowerShell script in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:

   `New-SPSite -Name "Wingtip Intranet" -Url "http://intranet.wingtip.com" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "STS#0" -OwnerAlias "WINGTIP\Administrator"`
5. Create a developer site by executing the following Windows PowerShell script in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:

   `New-SPSite -Name "Wingtip Developer Site" -Url "http://dev.wingtip.com" –HostHeaderWebApplication $hnscWebApp -Template "DEV#0" -OwnerAlias "WINGTIP\Administrator"`

   You can only create, debug and test apps using a developer site.

At this point you now have a site collection to use as a team site (http://intranet.wingtip.com) and to develop and test custom SharePoint apps (http://dev.wingtip.com).

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the site with `New-SpSite` try to create the bindings (this must be done on each WFE server of your farm):

```
New-WebBinding -Name "intranet.wingtip.com" -HostHeader "wingtip.com"
```